# combining dataframes based on conditions using merge function - R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with some characteristics of diamonds:

```
structure(list(carat = c("Above average", "Above average", "Below average", 
"Above average", "Below average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", 
"Below average", "Very Good", "Below average", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Above average", "Above average", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Below average", "Below average", "Very Good", 
"Below average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", 
"Very Good", "Above average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", 
"Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", 
"Below average", "Below average", "Below average", "Very Good", 
"Above average", "Above average", "Above average", "Below average", 
"Below average", "Below average", "Above average", "Very Good", 
"Below average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Above average", "Above average", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Below average", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Above average", "Above average", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Above average", "Very Good", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Above average", "Above average", 
"Below average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", 
"Very Good", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Above average", "Above average", 
"Below average", "Above average", "Above average", "Above average", 
"Above average", "Above average", "Above average", "Below average", 
"Above average", "Very Good", "Very Good", "Below average", "Below average", 
"Below average", "Very Good", "Above average"), color = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 2L, 6L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 2L, 1L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 
4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 5L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"), class = "factor"), 
    clarity = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 
    3L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 
    7L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 2L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), 
    price = c(481, 481, 492, 558, 568, 579, 579, 590, 590, 601, 
    610, 621, 642, 660, 671, 671, 700, 729, 729, 729, 729, 740, 
    750, 750, 750, 761, 772, 793, 793, 793, 951, 951, 951, 951, 
    951, 951, 951, 951, 952, 952, 952, 952, 952, 952, 952, 952, 
    952, 952, 953, 953, 953, 953, 953, 953, 953, 954, 954, 954, 
    954, 954, 958, 958, 958, 958, 958, 959, 959, 959, 959, 959, 
    959, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 
    960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 960, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2, 3, 3), cut_new = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Above average", "Below average", 
    "Very Good"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("carat", "color", 
"clarity", "price", "cut_new"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

for each combination of `color` and `cut_new` I have calculated the mean values:

```
structure(c(484.29290617849, 417.560131795717, 463.579787234043, 
514.823308270677, 534.805128205128, 574.193661971831, 605.398230088496, 
470.268456375839, 482.971830985916, 541.042253521127, 542.464788732394, 
504.777777777778, 461.622857142857, 469.469465648855, 485.88986784141, 
540.725490196078, 494.36, 640.603448275862), .Dim = c(6L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), c("Above average", "Below average", 
    "Very Good")))
```

Now i would like to create a data frame that contains my information on the diamonds + a column so that for every diamond I see the price and next to it also the average price (based on combination of 
color and cut_new).

I have tried using the function `merge`, but get an error:

```
results <- merge (diamonds_2, mean, by.x = "cut_new", by.y= "color")
```

any tips?

**EDIT**
I want the result to look like: 
[image]

THANKS

Comment: It is not clear from the input example how you want the expected.  Could you show the expected for few lines

Comment: @akrun, thanks for pointing that out. I have added a screeshot of how the result should look like, hope it clarifies my objective

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `tidyverse` and `base` example to calculate the mean by color and cut_new. I believe this is what you want, but there is no merging involved. Assuming you call the dataframe above "df".

```
# tidyverse
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(color, cut_new) %>% 
  mutate(price.m = mean(price))

# Base
df2 <- transform(df, price.m = ave(price, color, cut_new))
```